# Nautilus so slow, if there are so many files/folder in an opened directory

Tags: nautilus

I have a lot of MarkDown notes in a folder. It is like a directory with ~500 folders inside. When I opened using Nautilus and trying to do some operations (rename, copy , paste) it always lags.

I am using X220, with 8 GB RAM.

Is this behavior apply only to certain cases or is it "intended" behavior?
I was using Caja in Ubuntu MATE and it was fine.

Comment: I don't use Nautilus so can't test, but try turning off thumbnails, that might make it faster? Otherwise, it may be counting all the files in all the subfolders, so it can tell you each folder has X files or Y bytes, turning that off should help, if it's the chokepoint?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? I need in anyway to faster my Nautilus performance due to deadline approaching.

Comment: I don't use Nautilus so don't know how, could be in a GUI settings page (easy), or a config file or "hidden" setting you edit in (less easy), or at the worst could remove the features fromthe source code & recompile (not really easy). Try a web search to turn off or stop the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

It is a well known old issue (at least since 2011). You can see the launchpad bug report:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/869793

And the related upstream nautilus bug:

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/978

The solution has historically been to install Thunar or any other file manager.

Although some issues remain (right click, properties takes ages), in the last few years the situation has improved a lot.

There are still some issues if you use insync (https://forums.insynchq.com/t/insync-nautilus-makes-opening-folders-with-many-files-very-slow/17268).

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that helped me was disabling previews and file counts.

[image: Search, preview and file counts preferences]

Another one was disabling some columns. I had a feeling that disabling "detailed type" helped, but I'm not sure to be honest.

[image]

I couldn't get thunar's level of performance though.